# probability distribution function of independent exponential random variables

Tags: probability

I have encountered a problem in my work, I need to find the below mentioned probability distribution function where U,V and T are my independent exponential random variables with parameters $\lambda_u$, $\lambda_v$,$\lambda_t$   and a,b,c,D are constants. I could not find the way to proceed further to find the distribution of such an expression. 
I have tried to find the exact distribution but got stuck because of few problems like pdf of product of two exponential variables are not exponential, Independence is also a problem in my scenario when I try to find the distribution.
Is there any way I can proceed to find the exact distribution? Or is there any approximate technique to solve such a thing?

$$P({UV  \over aU+bT+cVT}\leqslant D)$$

I would be really thankful :)

Comment: monte carlo can give you a sense of empirical behaviors

Comment: have you tried subsets of this problem ... for instance if expression was simply $P(UV\le D)$

Comment: and then $P(aU+bT+cV\le D)$

Comment: thanks for the help. yes I have tried the subsets but eventually it turns up into the distribution other than exponential distribution and independence becomes the issue, so I could not continue with the same approach